# Despite including " :autosave => true" in my model, Rails is not saving my assocation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, belongs-to, autosave

I’m using Rails 4.2.3  In my database, I have a “my_objects” table with an “address_id” that is a foreign key back to the “addresses” table.  I have this in my app/models/my_object.rb file …

```
class MyObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address, :autosave => true, dependent: :destroy
  attr_accessor :address, :hour, :minute, :second, :location
```

Then in my app/controller/my_objects_controller.rb I have

```
  def create
    @my_object = MyObject.new(my_object_params)
…
    respond_to do |format|
      if @my_object.save
        format.html { redirect_to controller: "my_objects", action: "index", notice: 'Saved successfully.' }
        format.js { render js: "window.location='/my_objects'" }
      else
        format.html { render action: "index" }
        format.json { render json: @my_object.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js { render json: { errors: @my_object.errors, success: false }, content_type: 'application/json' }
      end

  private

    def my_object_params
      params.require(:my_object).permit(:name, :day, :distance, :distance_unit_id, address: [:city, :state_id, :country_id], my_object_times_attributes: [:time_in_ms, :overall_rank, :age_group_rank, :gender_rank])
    end
```

However, when I save submit my form to the “create” method, with these parameters

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "my_object"=>{"id"=>"", "name"=>"DaveRace2", "day"=>"07/06/2016", "distance"=>"3", "distance_unit_id"=>"4", "hour"=>"00", "minute"=>"12", "second"=>"05", "address"=>{"city"=>"austin"}, "my_object_times_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"overall_rank"=>"", "age_group_rank"=>"", "gender_rank"=>"", "time_in_ms"=>"725000"}}}, "state"=>"AR", "country"=>{"country_id"=>"233"}, "commit"=>"Save"}
```

No address object is created in my “my_objects” table.  All the other fields are populated, but the address_id column is blank.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In my initial observation,

```
"address"=>{"city"=>"austin"}
```

In the above hash, address is of type 'text'.

And you mentioned about foreign-key "address_id" which might be 'integer'.

There might be datatype problem.

Comment: Thanks for describign the problem but I am not clear what the actual "answer" is from waht you've listed.  What would I need to do to correct the problem?

Comment: have you set    has_many :my_objects   in your address.rb model ?

Comment: I did "has_one", my reasoning being an address can only be associated with a single "my_object."

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the duplicate definition of `#address` be getting in the way? You've set it up as both an association (with `belongs_to`) and an instance variable (with `attr_accessor`).

Ooh, was `attr_accessor` supposed to be `attr_accessible`?